# contemplate--meaning and usage

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Dictionary lists out the following meanings and usages of the word "contemplate"

> Verb 1. If you contemplate an action, you think about whether to do it
> or not.
>  Verb 2: If you contemplate an idea or subject, you think about
> it carefully for a long time. 
> Verb 3: If you contemplate something or
> someone, you look at them for a long time.
>  He contemplated his hands,
> still frowning.
>  contemplation UNCOUNTABLE NOUN
>  He was lost in the
> contemplation of the landscape for a while.

I found in a script, where the writer uses the word contemplate to convey the meaning "with thoughts about someone"

> She deeply contemplated her dying brother.
>  (this brother is not before her. He is far away in a different city. She leaves immediately to see him after this)

Is it right to use this word in this particular context? From what I understand from the dictionary, when you contemplate someone, you actually look at them for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to question this usage. I think it is acceptable but awkward. It's using meaning (2) from your quoted definition. The dying brother - really the brother's imminent death - is the subject of her contemplation.